# Generic Type WebMethod in web service

Tags: c#, web-services, generics, asmx, webmethod

I need to write a webmethod with Generic type because I will return string or XmlDocument. There is my codes;

```
[WebMethod]
public T test<T>()
{

    var type = Context.Request.QueryString["type"];

    if (type == "json")
    {
        string result = "";
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        XmlDocument result = new XmlDocument();
        return result;
    }

}
```

Error is  :

> cannot convert string to T or XmlDocument to T.

What is mistakes here?

Comment: the compiler does not know in advance which type you will give him when you call this method. You will need a variable `T result` if you want to return it.

Comment: you could return an object instead of a specific type.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Serialization is performed by the framework based on configuration and *well-known* headers like `content-type`. Web methods on the other hand define *well-known and defined* operations, they can't be generic. In this case, they don't need to. The same method can return Json or SOAP if the *request* is properly made

Comment: I want a webmethod which will return json or xml. And this webmethod will be call like ../..asmx/testmethod?type=json. How should i do this? Any suggestion will be fine. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Just check the framework documentation and do it in the way the *framework* wants. Clients will be very annoyed if you ignore the standard `Accept: application/json` request header. Otherwise you'll have to create custom bindings/serializers and configure your endpoints to use them - that's what converts whatever you return to JSON or SOAP

Comment: BTW ASMX is deprecated. It's WCF that supports both JSON and SOAP. Are you really using ASMX or did you use the wrong tag? ASMX will wrap whatever you return in a SOAP message even if it's only a string

Comment: Also notice that I say SOAP, not XML. Web Services deal with SOAP, which has a specific format and *very* specific request/response requirements. If you want to return arbitrary JSON or XML, you should be looking at Web API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use generic methods in web service

Comment: Any suggestion for this problem? I want to take type from querystring and want to return this type?

Comment: @AdemBüyük the problem is the design itself. There is no such thing as a "generic" web service. They all have contracts schemas, exposed in WSDLs. You can't do that if you don't know the type. BTW WCF already supports returning SOAP or JSON based on the request.